# Build ics-openvpn success but no apk file

Tags: android, openvpn

I use IDEA to with gradle 1.7 to build ics-openvpn, but i have no apk file
the message is

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3.77 secs
```

what's problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try building it without an IDEA first. Process is described in the readme.

Answer (score 0):

Clean and rebuild project. Try to run project and check on emulator or device.
And you can see apk file in build/output folder.

Answer (score 0):

Follow what [plaisthos](https://stackoverflow.com/users/325102/plaisthos) Said.

If you are a Linux user then try to make sure that, the first time you build the project by command line. In this project, some issue will be rise that is very difficult to catch by IDE but very easy to catch by command line Gradle build. So...

Go to your project location by the conventional producer using command line and type: `gradle build`. The whole project will take 8-10 min (+-) to be built. If you get any error then solve that.

First time I have faced a lot of problems to get the Apk. After that, I solved that by using these tricks.